# Using multiple limitTo filters in one ng-repeat directive in AngularJS1

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json

My data is fetched from JSON file, by PHP, from MySQL database (XAMPP - virtual server, REST API) to AngularJS1.

Let's say that now I have a JSON with numbers, from 1 to 31 and that I want to display, by expression in AngularJS1, numbers from 8 to 14. Is it possible to somehow use two `limitTo` filters in one `ng-repeat` directive, which could limit the output of {{expression}} FROM - TO some range of data? I don't want to manipulate with my PHP and MySQL code.

Answer (score 3):

you can create a custom filter and call it from the ng-repeat

```
.filter('slice', function() {
  return function(arr, start, end) {
    return (arr || []).slice(start, end);
  };
});
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.arr = [];
for(var i=1; i<=31; i++){
  $scope.arr.push(i)
}
}).filter('slice', function() {
  return function(arr, start, end) {
    return (arr || []).slice(start, end);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div ng-repeat="item in arr  | slice:8:14">
  {{item}}
</div>
</div>
```